# Access query results in Facebook C# SDK v6

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

In previous versions I was able to retrieve the results from a query using:

```
            var facebookClient = new Facebook.FacebookClient(accessToken);
            const string fqlQuery = "select pic_big from user where uid=me()";
            dynamic result = facebookClient.Query(fqlQuery);

            var profilePhotoUrl = result[0].pic_big.ToString();
```

In version 6, I can accomplish the same, but using:

```
            var facebookClient = new Facebook.FacebookClient(accessToken);
            const string fqlQuery = "select pic_big from user where uid=me()";
            dynamic result = facebookClient.Get("fql", new { q = fqlQuery });

            var profilePhotoUrl = result.data[0].pic_big.ToString(); //v6.0 requires us to add ".data[0]" field
```

The new way work, but I just want to make sure that: `result.data[0].pic_big.ToString()` is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes your new call including the data property is correct. I'm not sure about the reason behind the change. Including the data property mimics the JSON structure of the results more accurate, but because I don't know if the data element was already present or not.

Anyway: using the data property is the way to go from now on!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a clarification on why you need `.data` in v6.

In v5 we used rest api for fql as it was not yet available in graph api. Rest api did not wrap around `data` so you never had to use `.data`. In some later versions of v5 we used moved to graph api when fb announced support for fql using graph api, but to avoid breaking changes in v5, the sdk internally removed the `.data` before returning the result to the user (ugly hack).

Here is how v5 worked when fql used graph api.

```
public virtual object Query(string fql)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fql))
        throw new ArgumentNullException("fql");

    var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    parameters["q"] = fql;

        // when using graph api
    var result = (IDictionary<string, object>)Get("fql", parameters);
    return result["data"];

    /*
        // when using rest api
    var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    parameters["query"] = fql;
    parameters["method"] = "fql.query";

    return Get(parameters);
    */
}
```

So users did not even know about this transparency. Since v6 is a major release we removed the `Query` due to this ugly hack workaround. The only way to use fql was via calling the normal get. Since this return the exact result what fb gives, you needed to include `.data`.